# Unexpected behavior with STR_TO_DATE()

Tags: mysql, datetime

The following returns a bunch of row from my DB:

```
USE test;
SELECT * FROM aaaa
WHERE dddd BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 42 DAY) AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 42 DAY)
```

But for reasons I do not understand the following query returns nothing:

```
USE test;
SELECT * FROM aaaa
WHERE dddd BETWEEN (STR_TO_DATE('2014/6/6', '%Y,%m,%d') - INTERVAL 42 DAY) AND (STR_TO_DATE('2014/6/6', '%Y,%m,%d') + INTERVAL 42 DAY)
```

Shouldn't it return a similar number of rows? Its the same day so why, when I convert it to datetime, does it return nothing? I get no errors.

Comment: what am i missing? isn't this just a simple, typographical error right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in a `/`-separated date, but telling MySQL it's `,`-separated. Since you have no `,` in your string, the format doesn't apply, and you end up with an invalid date.

Try

```
STR_TO_DATE('2014/6/6', '%Y/%m/%d')
```

instead...

"invalid - 42 days = invalid", not something 42 days ago.

Comment: Ha well that was easy- but why isn't an error thrown if the date is invalid?

Comment: MySQL by default runs in a "lax" mode, where such things would only cause a warning. You want a stricter mode, e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-full

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
STR_TO_DATE('2014/6/6', '%Y/%m/%d')
```

Note the `/` instead of `,` in the date format. ;)